# How to make github STFU about deleting branch after merge

Tags: github

My normal workflow is I commit to my "dev" branch, then merge to "master" when I'm ready to release.  I use github's pull request mechanism to do the merge.  After each merge, I get prompted:

```
request successfully merged and closed
You’re all set—the dev branch can be safely deleted
```

which might make sense for a short-lived topic branch, but I never want to delete "dev".  Is there some way to tell github to stop prompting me about this?  At best, it's a minor annoyance.  At worst, there's a "Delete branch" button just begging to be clicked by accident.

Comment: i think protected branches will never prompt for deletion, but thats included in github pro only https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches maybe you can create dummy pull request into dev so it always sees dependency.

Comment: Hmmm, that looks like it might work.  My repo is public, which allows protected branches.  I just enabled that and we'll see what happens the next time I merge.  Thanks.

Comment: @RoySmith, What happens if you click the delete. then go to the closed pullrequest page and undelete it. Is it a complete undo operation or is there data loss?